# Create callback Class

Tags: java, android, firebase, callback, asynccallback

Hey I am using firebase callback that call PhoneAuthProvider
what I want to do is to wrap this callback in class and create an instance of this class in multiple Classes instead of writing this callback multiple times (try to write 'clean
code')
I can I do that ?
and I want also to add parameters to the functions
how can I do that?

```
    private final PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            final String code = credential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                verifycode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s,
                               @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, token);
            verificationID = s;
/*
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Code sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
*/
          /*  btnJoinNl.setEnabled(true);
            codeFunc(s);*/
/*
            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
*/
        }


   };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move the construction to a method which will be called from different places. Then the actual construction of the instance is only written once (but called many times).

But it's also possible to write this as a standalone class. Usually your IDE (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse) provides this transformation as part of its "refactoring" actions. Here's how the result would look like:

```
public class MyCallback extends PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks {
    private String verificationID;

    public String getVerificationID() {
        return verificationID;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        final String code = credential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            verifycode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s,
                           @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, token);
        verificationID = s;
    }

    private void verifyCode(final String code) {
        // verify ...
    }
}
```

---

As requested, here is how you would create the instance from a method:

```
private final PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        mCallbacks = createCallback();

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks createCallBack() {
    return new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        /* override methods here ... */
    };
}
```

Both variants can be combined, so you can first extract a class, then have a method create instances of that class.

Comment: Thank u very much , can you explain the first solution with the method?

Comment: @NMZ instead of assign the variable directly with `yourvar = new …`, move the `new` expression block into a method, then call the method: `yourvar = methodCall()`. The method is implemented as `return new …`

Comment: Can you please write a sample of this?

Comment: @NMZ done. Although I suggest avoiding anonymous classes and callback objects if methods are difficult to understand at the moment. Start slower with simpler command line programs.

Comment: okay thank u a lot , which approach u think is more better for "clean code" ?

Comment: @NMZ there is no one answer. It depends on your class structure, your memory requirements, dependencies between your classes, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251154/discussion-between-n-mz-and-knittl).